# How can I do a regex replacement called from an array

Tags: javascript, regex, regexp-replace

I am trying to do some replace actions on a string.
the replace actions are stored in an array.
Everything goes well up to the 3rd action.
I can't get that one to work and don't understand why.
It does not give an error but just does not perform the last replacement
`"/(\d{1,5})/([A-Z]{3})/g","$2/$1"`

The 1st replacement replaces all spaces with slashes
the 2nd replacement moves down the string on the right side (inserts a new line)
The 3rd replacement should swap `ESB` strings with the 4 digits in front of it

For example

`AR/PAG30079XZ/2213/ESB/ABC` would then become 
`AR/PAG30079XZ/ESB/2213/ABC`

It's this last part that does not work

This is what I got so far:

```js
function autoPlay(){
 var arr = [
    ["/ +/g","/"],
    ["/(?=[A-Z]R/)/g","$&\n"],
    ["/(\d{1,5})/([A-Z]{3})/g","$2/$1"]
    ];
 var arrL = arr.length;
 var str = document.getElementById('val');
 for (var i = 0; i < arrL; i++) { 
  var parts = /\/(.*)\/(.*)/.exec(arr[i][0]);
  var restoredRegex = new RegExp(parts[1], parts[2]);
  var result = str.innerHTML.replace(restoredRegex, arr[i][1]);
  str.innerHTML = result
 }
}
```

```css
#val{
  border: 1px solid grey;
  padding: 5px;
  height: 300px;
  width: 500px;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<button type="button" onClick="autoPlay()">
GO
</button>
<pre id="val" contenteditable="true" spellcheck="false">
AL PAG31503XZ 2351 ESB ABC  AR PAG30079XZ 2213 ESB ABC
BL PMC16410R7 1798 ESB ABC  BR PMC27936XZ 2444 ESB ABC
CL PMC27377XZ 2563 ESB ABC  CR PMC21402XZ 2622 ESB ABC
DL PMC24300XZ 2404 ESB ABC  DR PMC26742XZ 2446 ESB ABC 
EL PMC23546XZ 2682 ESB ABC  ER PMC27450XZ 2774 ESB ABC
FL PMC22126C6 3022 ESB ABC  FR PMC21220XZ 3292 ESB ABC
GL PMC21077XZ 2982 ESB ABC  GR PMC28748XZ 2998 ESB ABC
HL PMC26051XZ 2492 ESB ABC  HR PMC53510R7 2928 ESB ABC
JL PMC24177XZ 3014 ESB ABC  JR PMC21444XZ 2873 ESB ABC
KL PMC24466XZ 2781 ESB ABC  KR PMC21778XZ 2513 ESB ABC
LL PMC22897XZ 2454 ESB ABC  LR PMC26473XZ 2778 ESB ABC
ML PMC27854XZ 2824 ESB ABC  MR PMC26001XZ 3218 ESB ABC
PL PAJ1129 XZ 2279 ESB ABC  PR PAJ51477XZ 2398 ESB ABC
RC PMC58993R7 2176 ESB ABC    
LOWER DECK
FWD
11P PMC28357XZ 1122 ESB ABC
12P PMC24753XZ 1589 ESB ABC
13P PMC26671XZ 1862 ESB ABC 
21P PMC28016XZ 3386 ESB ABC
</pre>
```

Comment: Your question is not clear will you what is the expected output.what problem you're facing with third one ?

Comment: @benvc, Sorry for that. There are no errors.

Comment: @Code Maniac. The thing is that the third one doesn't do anything, no errors, no result. The third action should swap the values "ESB" with the numbers in front of it.

Comment: Just going to throw it out there that you could simplify your code and headaches dealing with it if you make your flags a separate element in your array, and remove the delimiters from your patterns. This will allow for a straight passthrough.  (But you still need to properly escape things)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your \ in \d in your 3rd regex lacks escaping. Take a look:

```js
function autoPlay(){
    var arr = [
 ["/ +/g","/"],
 ["/(?=[A-Z]R/)/g","$&\n"],
 ["/(\\d{1,5})/([A-Z]{3})/g","$2\/$1"]
    ];
    var arrL = arr.length;
    var str = document.getElementById('val');
    for (var i = 0; i < arrL; i++) { 
 var parts = /\/(.*)\/(.*)/.exec(arr[i][0]);
      var restoredRegex = new RegExp(parts[1], parts[2]);    
 var result = str.innerHTML.replace(restoredRegex, arr[i][1]);
 str.innerHTML = result
    }
}
```

```css
#val{
  border: 1px solid grey;
  padding: 5px;
  height: 300px;
  width: 500px;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<button type="button" onClick="autoPlay()">
GO
</button>
<pre id="val" contenteditable="true" spellcheck="false">
AL PAG31503XZ 2351 ESB ABC  AR PAG30079XZ 2213 ESB ABC
BL PMC16410R7 1798 ESB ABC  BR PMC27936XZ 2444 ESB ABC
CL PMC27377XZ 2563 ESB ABC  CR PMC21402XZ 2622 ESB ABC
DL PMC24300XZ 2404 ESB ABC  DR PMC26742XZ 2446 ESB ABC 
EL PMC23546XZ 2682 ESB ABC  ER PMC27450XZ 2774 ESB ABC
FL PMC22126C6 3022 ESB ABC  FR PMC21220XZ 3292 ESB ABC
GL PMC21077XZ 2982 ESB ABC  GR PMC28748XZ 2998 ESB ABC
HL PMC26051XZ 2492 ESB ABC  HR PMC53510R7 2928 ESB ABC
JL PMC24177XZ 3014 ESB ABC  JR PMC21444XZ 2873 ESB ABC
KL PMC24466XZ 2781 ESB ABC  KR PMC21778XZ 2513 ESB ABC
LL PMC22897XZ 2454 ESB ABC  LR PMC26473XZ 2778 ESB ABC
ML PMC27854XZ 2824 ESB ABC  MR PMC26001XZ 3218 ESB ABC
PL PAJ1129 XZ 2279 ESB ABC  PR PAJ51477XZ 2398 ESB ABC
RC PMC58993R7 2176 ESB ABC    
LOWER DECK
FWD
11P PMC28357XZ 1122 ESB ABC
12P PMC24753XZ 1589 ESB ABC
13P PMC26671XZ 1862 ESB ABC 
21P PMC28016XZ 3386 ESB ABC
</pre>
```

If you try to do a console log after this line:

```
var parts = /\/(.*)\/(.*)/.exec(arr[i][0]);
```

you'll see that in your 3rd pass the returned parts are: `"(d{1,5})/([A-Z]{3})"` and  `"g"`

even better, if you do a simple `console.log("/(\d{1,5})/([A-Z]{3})/g")` you'll get the answer: `"/(d{1,5})/([A-Z]{3})/g"`

That's because js treats a \d as a escaped character *at string level* before you process it with the first regex. So just reescape the \d (\\d) and your're done.

A better version of this code would be:

```js
function autoPlay(){
    var arr = [
 ["/ +/g","/"],
 ["/(?=[A-Z]R/)/g","$&\n"],
 ["/(\\d{1,5})/([A-Z]{3})/g","$2\/$1"]
    ];
    var str = document.getElementById('val');
    arr.map((re)=>{
        var parts = /\/(.*)\/(.*)/.exec(re[0]);
        str.innerHTML = str.innerHTML.replace( 
            new RegExp(parts[1], parts[2]), 
            re[1]);
    })
}
```

```css
#val{
  border: 1px solid grey;
  padding: 5px;
  height: 300px;
  width: 500px;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<button type="button" onClick="autoPlay()">
GO
</button>
<pre id="val" contenteditable="true" spellcheck="false">
AL PAG31503XZ 2351 ESB ABC  AR PAG30079XZ 2213 ESB ABC
BL PMC16410R7 1798 ESB ABC  BR PMC27936XZ 2444 ESB ABC
CL PMC27377XZ 2563 ESB ABC  CR PMC21402XZ 2622 ESB ABC
DL PMC24300XZ 2404 ESB ABC  DR PMC26742XZ 2446 ESB ABC 
EL PMC23546XZ 2682 ESB ABC  ER PMC27450XZ 2774 ESB ABC
FL PMC22126C6 3022 ESB ABC  FR PMC21220XZ 3292 ESB ABC
GL PMC21077XZ 2982 ESB ABC  GR PMC28748XZ 2998 ESB ABC
HL PMC26051XZ 2492 ESB ABC  HR PMC53510R7 2928 ESB ABC
JL PMC24177XZ 3014 ESB ABC  JR PMC21444XZ 2873 ESB ABC
KL PMC24466XZ 2781 ESB ABC  KR PMC21778XZ 2513 ESB ABC
LL PMC22897XZ 2454 ESB ABC  LR PMC26473XZ 2778 ESB ABC
ML PMC27854XZ 2824 ESB ABC  MR PMC26001XZ 3218 ESB ABC
PL PAJ1129 XZ 2279 ESB ABC  PR PAJ51477XZ 2398 ESB ABC
RC PMC58993R7 2176 ESB ABC    
LOWER DECK
FWD
11P PMC28357XZ 1122 ESB ABC
12P PMC24753XZ 1589 ESB ABC
13P PMC26671XZ 1862 ESB ABC 
21P PMC28016XZ 3386 ESB ABC
</pre>
```

Comment: Thanks for such  a neat answer.i got to know the problem is because of \d but didn't know why it is so replaced it with [0-9] and made it work.But this makes more sense. :)

Comment: Thank you for the explanation Nelson, That's very helpful. I got it working now!

Answer (score 0):

**I made it work.**

Problem is due to \d.

```js
function autoPlay(){
 var arr = [
    [" +", "g" ,"/"],
    ["(?=[A-Z]R/)", "g","$&\n"],
    ["([0-9]{1,5})\/([A-Z]{3})" ,"g", "$2/$1"]
    ];
 var arrL = arr.length;
 var str = document.getElementById('val');
 for (var i = 0; i < arrL; i++) {
  var restoredRegex = new RegExp(arr[i][0], arr[i][1]);
  var result = str.innerHTML.replace(restoredRegex, arr[i][2]);
  str.innerHTML = result
 }
}
```

```css
#val{
  border: 1px solid grey;
  padding: 5px;
  height: 300px;
  width: 500px;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<button type="button" onClick="autoPlay()">
GO
</button>
<pre id="val" contenteditable="true" spellcheck="false">
AL PAG31503XZ 2351 ESB ABC  AR PAG30079XZ 2213 ESB ABC
BL PMC16410R7 1798 ESB ABC  BR PMC27936XZ 2444 ESB ABC
CL PMC27377XZ 2563 ESB ABC  CR PMC21402XZ 2622 ESB ABC
DL PMC24300XZ 2404 ESB ABC  DR PMC26742XZ 2446 ESB ABC 
EL PMC23546XZ 2682 ESB ABC  ER PMC27450XZ 2774 ESB ABC
FL PMC22126C6 3022 ESB ABC  FR PMC21220XZ 3292 ESB ABC
GL PMC21077XZ 2982 ESB ABC  GR PMC28748XZ 2998 ESB ABC
HL PMC26051XZ 2492 ESB ABC  HR PMC53510R7 2928 ESB ABC
JL PMC24177XZ 3014 ESB ABC  JR PMC21444XZ 2873 ESB ABC
KL PMC24466XZ 2781 ESB ABC  KR PMC21778XZ 2513 ESB ABC
LL PMC22897XZ 2454 ESB ABC  LR PMC26473XZ 2778 ESB ABC
ML PMC27854XZ 2824 ESB ABC  MR PMC26001XZ 3218 ESB ABC
PL PAJ1129 XZ 2279 ESB ABC  PR PAJ51477XZ 2398 ESB ABC
RC PMC58993R7 2176 ESB ABC    
LOWER DECK
FWD
11P PMC28357XZ 1122 ESB ABC
12P PMC24753XZ 1589 ESB ABC
13P PMC26671XZ 1862 ESB ABC 
21P PMC28016XZ 3386 ESB ABC
</pre>
```

**P.S** - It was making problem due \d. (Didn't knew why it is happening before @
Nelson Teixeira's answer so i made it work with some `Juggad` by replacing \d with [0-9] ).